# Split a string around any characters not specified

Tags: python, regex, string

I am looking to be able to split a string into a list around anything that is not a numeral or a dot.  Currently the split method only provides a way of doing a positive match for split, is a regex the best route to take in this situation?

For example, given the string `"10.23, 10.13.21; 10.1 10.5 and 10.23.32"`
This should return the list `['10.23', '10.13.21', '10.1', '10.5', '10.23.32']`

As such I believe the best regex to use in this situation would be...
`[\d\.]+`

Is this the best way to handle such a case?

Comment: I agree that a regex seems to be the best fit in this situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case you are thinking of `re.findall`: you can use `re.split` with an inverted version of your regex:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = "10.23, 10.13.21; 10.1 10.5 and 10.23.32"

In [3]: re.split(r'[^\d\.]+', s)
Out[3]: ['10.23', '10.13.21', '10.1', '10.5', '10.23.32']
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for, I don't mind using regular expressions it was just an extra level of complexity to get the matches and then build my own list, which I wanted to avoid, so this is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a solution other than regex, you could use `str.translate` and translate everything other than `'.0123456789'` into whitespace and make a call to `split()`

```
In [69]: mystr
Out[69]: '10.23, 10.13.21; 10.1 10.5 and 10.23.32'

In [70]: mystr.translate(' '*46 + '. ' + '0123456789' + ' '*198).split()
Out[70]: ['10.23', '10.13.21', '10.1', '10.5', '10.23.32']
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

An arguably better readable form of what @inspectorG4dget proposed:

```
>>> import string
>>> s = '10.23, 10.13.21; 10.1 10.5 and 10.23.32'
>>> ''.join(c if c in set(string.digits + '.') else ' ' for c in s).split()
['10.23', '10.13.21', '10.1', '10.5', '10.23.32']
```

This way you can avoid regular expressions, which is often a good idea when you quite easily can.